# Using duplicates method in Laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have two collections and want to find the same or duplicated items inside two collections. My solution is first merging two collections and create one collection and then using duplicates method find the same items, but I have an error.

```php
$t1 = collect([12, 13, 11]);
$t2 = collect([14, 15, 12, 11]);
$t3 = $t1->merge($t2);
$final = $t3->duplicates();
```

Error

> BadMethodCallException   Method
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection::duplicates does not exist.

Comment: What is the exact version of Laravel you're using?

Comment: version 5.8.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my laravel version was 5.8 and i updated project using `composer update` and now my laravel version is 5.8.17 and my problem soloved.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the items which are present in the two collections, you can use Laravel collection [intersect method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-intersect)